# Website running on tomcat talking to another website on same machine but different server

Tags: web-services, tomcat, proxy, webserver, eclipse-virgo

I have two servers installed on my machine, Tomcat and Virgo, (an OSGi webserver) that run on different ports. I need a website deployed on Tomcat to link to another website deployed on the other server (which is not mapped to any address), how can I do this? Resolving client side the ip address of the server? What is the correct approach?
Thanks.

**Requirement is: The user browsing one app will need to be able to click on a link to the other app.**

Comment: Do you mean a server to server call (in which case why not use localhost)? Or do you mean a user browsing one app needs to see a link to the other app?

Comment: No it's not server to server call. It's client to same ip different address. Referencing the server using localhost client side doesn't work for obvious reason. Requirement is: The user browsing one app will need to be able to click on a link to the other app.

Comment: You can find the URL of webapp A from the request, chop it up to remove the webapp name and everything after and then append the name of webapp B

Answer (score 1):

From @Martin:

```
var url='//'+document.domain+':8080/otherapp/';
```